# A Question about defining $L^\infty$ norms through sup of $L^1$ ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at the proof the following lemma:
[image]
In the $p = \infty$ case, the consider the $\leq$ direction. And give the following reasoning:
[image]

1. I'm not obtaining the first equality $\int_X fg \, d\mu(x)  = \int_X |f|g_0 \, d\mu(x)$ when I substitute $g$.
2. Supposing we have this inequality -- why does the claim hold for the $\leq$ direction?

Comment: What did you try? And what is the definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ that you have?

Comment: For 1, I just tried plugging in the $g$ they defined. For 2. I'm not sure where to start. No defn for the norm is given -- I'm assuming its the essential sup.

Comment: I am quite confused.... Can you write down what you have done to show $fg = |f|g_0$? Also, please write down the definition of the essential supremum.

Comment: Sure: $fg$ = $f^2g_0/|f|$ and essential supremum is $\inf\{a \geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x) > a \})=0\}$

Comment: Do you realize that $f^2/|f| = |f|$?

Comment: I did not see that until now -- $f^2$ and $|f|^2$ are the same. Okay, but what about 2?

Comment: Maybe for number 2: essential supremum is $\sup\{\lambda > 0 | \mu(\{x : |f(x) > \lambda\})> 0\}$ - so then RHS is the infinity norm of $f$